# bitbucket CAPCHA locked error - keep coming

Tags: bitbucket

BELOW IS THE ERROR:

fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required
Your Bitbucket account has been locked. To unlock it and log in again you must
solve a CAPTCHA. This is typically caused by too many attempts to login with an
incorrect password. The account lock prevents your SCM client from accessing
Bitbucket and its mirrors until it is solved, even if you enter your password
correctly.

Comment: Have you contacted somebody about unlocking your account?

Comment: @JimRedmond - able to figured it out. Seems it's because of git-pull I created in jenkins job.

I am also the Bitbucket admi...

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause:** This issue occurs when user enters wrong password for 5 times.

**Solution:** Admin need to use "Clear Captcha" button against your respective user profile to fix this issue.